# Fat Free PHP: How to repeat over an int?

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

Using Fat Free PHP I am trying to repeat over an int value:

```
<repeat group="{{ @totalIterations }}" value="{{ @i }}">
     {{ @i }}<br/>
</repeat>
```

But it is not working, my desired result would be something like:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $totalIterations; $i++) {
     {{ @i }}<br/>
}
```

Comment: repeat group is equivialent of foreach in php. Loop would be the same as a for loop: http://fatfreeframework.com/quick-reference#loop

Comment: Thank you, I overlooked this section. If you put that in an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

repeat group is equivialent of foreach in php. Loop would be the same as a for loop:

```
<loop from="{{ @i=0 }}" to="{{ @i < @totalIterations }}" step="{{ @i++ }}">
    {{ @i }}<br/>
</loop>
```

[fat free documentation](http://fatfreeframework.com/quick-reference#loop)

Answer (score 0):

This should work as-well. I may need to test when I get home though

```
<repeat group="{{ range(0, 12) }}" value="{{ @i }}">
     {{ @i }}<br/>
</repeat>
```